# FromSqlRaw return value

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

My task is to return the number of cars where the age is more than three years

```
public IActionResult Report()
{
    var result = _context.Cars.FromSqlRaw("SELECT COUNT(*) from Car where (DATEDIFF(DAY, ReleaseDate, GetDate()) / 365.25) > 3");
    ViewBag.result = result;
    return View();
}
```

After spending time googling and studying Microsoft documentation I figured out that `FromSqlRaw` will work but in web form it returns either `-1` or `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.Entityqueryable<T>`.

A direct query to the database returns the correct value which is `1` car.
Adding any parameters after `FromSqlRaw` returns an exception.

I just don't get or getting `ReleaseDate` and then formatting and dividing it is too much?

Comment: `FromSqlRaw` returns the entity type, in this instance `Car`. I don't know how you're getting -1, but that is usually the result of "records effected" - - the result one gets from an ExecuteNonQuery call--when NoCount is On. You will likely need to compose this query with Linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FromSqlRaw` returns the entity type (`Car`) which is why you have this problem. It doesn't return arbitrary values (like the result of `COUNT()`). From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) (bolding mine):

> Raw SQL queries can return **regular entity types** or keyless entity
>   types that are **part of your model**.

You can construct this query with LINQ directly using [`EF.Functions.DateDiffDay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.datediffday?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions_DateDiffDay_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctions_System_DateTime_System_DateTime_) and `Count`. Assuming your entity has a property named `ReleaseDate`, this would look like the following:

```
var result = context.Cars.Where(
     c => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(c.ReleaseDate, DateTime.Now) / 365.25 > 3
).Count();
```

Or more concisely:

```
var result = context.Cars.Count(
    c => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(c.ReleaseDate, DateTime.Now) / 365.25 > 3
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Both worked flawlessly! I wasn't aware that you could do it this way.